How do I create a grid based on a list of coordinates?
I'm trying to solve a programming problem where I have a grid of pipes represented as a list of xy positions in a text file. I have to find out which ones are connected properly from their source to their destination.
Here's an example text file:

Here's the corresponding grid it represents:

I want to create the grid and iterate over it. I used pandas to read the text file and then turned the columns representing the x and y values into a list.
pipes = pd.read_csv("D:\pipe.txt", delimiter = ' ', header = None)
char = pipes[0].tolist()
x_val = pipes[1].tolist()
y_val = pipes[2].tolist()

I don't know if there are any libraries that can help with working with grids like this.

Based on the example you give, it looks like a "pipe" character would have openings on the top, bottom, left, and right sides. If we enter from one side, we can leave from any openings on any other side.
Given that, we can create a Pipe class to represent this structure:
class Pipe:
    def __init__(self, top, bottom, left, right):
        self.top = top
        self.bottom = bottom
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

In the Pipe class, top, bottom, left, and right are boolean values that represent if there's an opening there. For example, = would be Pipe(False, False, True, True).
You can then create a dictionary that maps these "pipe" characters to Pipe objects. Something like:
# I'm gonna assume you have a full list of "pipe" characters that will show up
pipe_mapping = {
    '=': Pipe(False, False, True, True),
    '‖': Pipe(True, True, False, False),
    '╬': Pipe(True, True, True, True),
    ...
}

With this mapping, we can now convert the txt file into a 2D list. So the example you gave would look like:
map = [
    ['*', Pipe(True, True, True, False), None, Pipe(False, True, False, True), Pipe(False, False, True, True), 'A'],
    [None, Pipe(True, True, False, True), Pipe(False, False, True, True), Pipe(True, False, True, False), None, None],
    ['C', None, Pipe(True, False, False, True), Pipe(False, False, True, True), 'B']
]

This is just pseudocode to explain the idea. I'll leave you to figure out how to represent *, A, B, C, and empty spaces under this context.
With this map, you can now implement your algorithm for this problem.
Hope it helps.

Okay that makes sense. Do you think I would be able to generalize this to hundreds of pipes? From what it looks like in your example you manually created the list.

There are about 8 different kinds of pipes that span a single grid

@Boltu So basically 8 entries in pipe_mapping dictionary, which you can create it manually. The 2D list could be trivially derived from the txt file using code. You just read the file line by line and for each line iterate over each character and use pipe_mapping to map the character to the corresponding object. I can write a demo for you if it's still unclear.

Let me include what the text file looks like in my original post. The text file isn't the grid, rather it's just the coordinates of the pipes on the actual grid. The original picture was just a representation of what the grid looks like when they were all plotted.

@Boltu I see. In that case, you need to calculate the dimension of the grid first. The width of the grid is the largest number in the second column. The height of the grid is the largest number in the third column. You then create the 2D list filled with None first. Then, for each pipe, you find its corresponding position in the 2D list and put the corresponding Pipe object there. Let me know if that's clear.
